# Jest mock imported function from library that is a function that returns a function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking, chakra-ui

I have some functionality where we display a chakra ui toast in an axios interceptor.

We use `createStandaloneToast` as per the [Chakra UI docs](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/feedback/toast) and do not duplicate the toast if the error is the same:

```
  const toast = createStandaloneToast();
  const status = response?.status ?? 400;
  
if (!toast.isActive(status)) {
    toast({
      id: status,
      position: 'top-right',
      title: i18n.t('ERROR.SERVER.TITLE', { status }),
      description,
      status: 'error',
      duration: null,
      isClosable: true,
    });
  }
```

In my companion unit test I can figure out how to mock `createStandaloneToast`:

```
jest.mock('@chakra-ui/react', () => {
  return {
    ...jest.requireActual('@chakra-ui/react'),
    createStandaloneToast: () => mockFn,
  };
});
```

But cannot figure out how to also mock the return value from `isActive` in the same way.

Can anyone help?